# Por qué el array retorna vacío o incompleto?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código cuya funcionalidad es, mediante ajax, obtener un listado de fichas de una base de datos.

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','proyectofinal')
or die(mysql_error($mysqli));

function consultar($cnx){

  $consulta = "SELECT * FROM fichas";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($cnx, $consulta);

  //$fichas = [];
  $fichas = Array();

  while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    // $fichas[] = $fila;
    array_push($fichas, $fila);
  }

  return $fichas;
}

echo json_encode(consultar($conexion));
?>
```

La cuestión es que cuando hago la petición el array que devuelve el método "consultar($cnx)" el array incompleto, en el peor de los casos, vacío. Cómo puedo hacer para que **SIEMPRE** devuelva el arreglo completo? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Puede haber otro proceso que te esté vaciando o modificando la tabla `fichas`? El resultado de tu código debería ser determinista, no aleatorio

Comment: Sí, uno que recorre un tablero para recolectar todas las fichas e ingresarlas a la tabla

Comment: Pues ahí lo tienes: detén ese proceso y que tu código siempre dé el mismo resultado. Si no es el que esperas, modifica tu pregunta añadiendo una copia de la tabla y así podamos ver qué está pasando para poder solucionarlo

Answer (score 1):

Pueden ser muchas cosas que no te esté devolviendo toda la información, uno de los errores podría ser la codificación de los caracteres, ponlo como utf8 y te recomiendo obtener el array en modo asociativo.

Te comparto tu mismo código con  algunas mejoras:

```php
$conexion = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'proyectofinal' )
or die( mysqli_error( $conexion ) ); // Aquí se utiliza es mysqli_error()

// Se establece el conjunto de caracteres
mysqli_set_charset( $conexion, 'utf8' );

function consultar( $cnx ) {

    $consulta  = "SELECT * FROM fichas";
    $resultado = mysqli_query( $cnx, $consulta );

    $fichas = [];

    // MYSQLI_ASSOC - Para obtener solo resultados con índices asociativos
    // O puedes utilizar la función mysqli_fetch_assoc( $resultado ) que hace lo mismo
    while ( $fila = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {
        $fichas[] = $fila;
    }

    return $fichas;

}

echo json_encode( consultar( $conexion ) );
```